# Start directory location from two levels up

Tags: perl, unix

I am doing a small app and I am trying to make it with the least amount of configuration required. The thing I am tackling now is the following:

in `project/lib/perl/`
I have my Modules.

My logs are in `project/log/` (I will probably move them in `/var/log/` at some point)

From my modules I want to write to the logs however I want to use a relative path. 
My initial attempt when setting the path to the log was `'../../log/development.log'` Which would work if it were terminal.

What is the cleanest way to achieve the desired directory switch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ever use relative paths like that, it's extremely brittle. Make the log location either a command-line option, configuration option (which just pushes the problem to specifying the config file location) or required environment variable.

Comment: JimGarrison- could you provide an example? I hear you can add paths to @INC

Comment: It's not a question of adding paths, it's the use of relative paths.  It may not be possible to go "up" two levels depending on where the package is installed, based on the filesystem location and/or permissions.  Depending on that directory structure is a recipe for headaches later.  It's the same concept as giving directions in terms of "left" and "right" instead of "north", "south", etc.  In the first case you're assuming the user is facing the correct direction.